# Concat html with jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a problem concating the html to jquery.

I have tried this :-

```
$('.dwrcwi_add_to_basket form').append('<input type="hidden" name="image" value="'+imagename+'"\'/">');
```

But it is returning like this :-

```
<input type="hidden" "="" '="" value="nav-shop-cart.png" name="image">
```

Can anyone help ? Also please explain what is the mistake? Or Provide me some tutorial regarding the concatination of these types.

Thanks.

Comment: The attributes in your output aren't even in the same order as your code.  Are you sure that **exact** code produced that **exact** output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got an extra single quote and an extra double quote:

```
'<input type="hidden" name="image" value="'+imagename+'"\'/">'
                                                        ^^ ^
```

They are probably confusing your browser's HTML parser (which is nice enough to parse the invalid HTML). I would recommend constructing a jQuery object instead:

```
$('<input>', {
    'type': 'hidden',
    'name': 'image',
    'value': imagename
}).appendTo('.dwrcwi_add_to_basket form');
```

Comment: this did not work. But this works :-
$('<input>', {'type': 'hidden','name': 'image','value': imagename}).appendTo('.dwrcwi_add_to_basket form');

Thanks. Great